# How to lookup an IP address in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, ip-address, vbscript

I'm working with a decent sized spreadsheet of domains and server names.  Another user of the spreadsheet needs the IP address for each of the DNS entries on the worksheet.  Instead of manually adding and then having to maintain this list, is there an easy way to do an IPAddress lookup to display the IP address in a cell?

I've seen some VBScripts that call GetHostByName, e.g.

```
Declare Function GetHostByName Lib "wsock32.dll" Alias "gethostbyname" (ByVal Host As String) As Long
```

However I'm not a VB expert so I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try visiting this [site](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/en-us/). Probably you'll need to adapt more than on script to fit all your needs.

For instance, [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/8ebcaa52-f5c0-4fc1-99fe-d1c8798fddf4) script will retrieve the IPs for an entire DNS server. You could adapt it walk an excel spreadsheet and retrieve just the ones that you need.

Comment: thanks Bob. I'll have a look around and check this if I find the solution.